# Variable set with `elif [[ -n ${var=$(mycommand ...args...)} ]]` unexpectedly empty

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

I'm not sure if this is a good way to define a variable inside an `elif` statement.

I want to set `VALUE` with the value of `CUSTOM_KEY` if it contains something else get the value from the configmap.

It seems that sometimes it can take few seconds to run the command in the second `elif` statement and I'm unsure if it can affect the result of the command.

```
if [[ -n "${CUSTOM_KEY}" ]]; then

    VALUE="${CUSTOM_KEY}"

    echo "VALUE: ${VALUE} set from CUSTOM_KEY"

elif [[ -n "${VALUE="$(kubectl get configmap configmapvalue -n "${N}" -o jsonpath="{.data.VALUE}")"}" ]]; then

     echo "VALUE: ${VALUE} set from configmap configmapvalue"

else

     echo "Please, define a CUSTOM_VALUE"

fi

echo "${VALUE}"
```

Comment: The only thing here that could possibly take a few seconds is the `kubectl get`. That's not a problem with bash `if` statements, it's a problem with kubectl -- and I don't know what you expect us to do about it.

Comment: That's right. `kubectl get` it might take few seconds and I'm unsure if that's the reason that I'm getting an empty string in `VALUE`.

Comment: Now, what _is_ a problem is trying to do an assignment with the wrong syntax. It has nothing to do with the delay.

Comment: Note that `${var=value}` is not the same as `${var:=value}`, because the former only modifies an unset variable. A variable _set to an empty value_ is still set.

Comment: I've checked if the `kubectl get .. ` assings something to `VALUE` and if i run an `echo "$(kubectl get configmap configmapvalue -n "${N}" -o jsonpath="{.data.VALUE}")"}"` I can see the value, but running the code in a pipeline it's not getting any value.

Comment: BTW, don't use all-caps names for your own variables; that's the namespace reserved for variables that reflect or modify shell builtin behavior. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a single namespace.

Comment: ("shell behavior" was a poor description; I should have said "OS-provided tool behavior" in the comment above)

Comment: Aside from the answer by Charles Duffy, you also have a weird quoting. Inside the string `"${VALUE="`, there is no closing parenthesis. For example,  the statement `: "${VALUE="'x}'` would be illegal, while `: "${VALUE="x}"' would set `VALUE` to _x_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is that `${var=value}` only assigns to `var` *when the variable is previously unset*.

We don't know that it's unset, because `[ -n "$var" ]` tests only if it's *empty*. A variable can be set to an empty value, in which case `${var=default}` won't change it, but `${var:=default}` will.

---

You don't need to use `${var=default}` *or* `${var:=default}`, though, because if the `elif` clause is executed at all, you *know* that you need to update the value from kubectl. Thus:

```
elif VALUE=$(kubectl get configmap configmapvalue -n "$N" -o jsonpath='{.data.VALUE}') && [[ $VALUE ]]; then
```

Comment: last `&& [[ $VALUE ]]` is not `&& [[ -n $VALUE ]]` instead?

Comment: @Shefferdock, they're 100% identical, so there's no reason to use the longer form.

Comment: Even `[ "$VALUE" ]` would be guaranteed to have the semantics we want; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html, and look for where it describes the "1 argument" case. (The thing `[[` buys us over `[` here is the ability to leave off the quotes).

Comment: Thanks. In case that `kubect get...`takes few seconds it woulnd't affect the execution of the command?

Comment: Correct. Command substitution blocks indefinitely until the FIFO connected to the stdout of the subprocess can be read in full.